# HTMLEditorExtender inside a repeater - buttons not rendering correctly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, .net-4.5, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a `HTMLEditorExtender` inside a repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptEditItem" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table border="0" style="width: 100%" class="DefaultText">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>             
            <td>
                <div class="containerClass">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEdit" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Eval("DisplayText") %>' Height="300px" Width="600px"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender1" DisplaySourceTab="true" TargetControlID="txtEdit" EnableSanitization="false" runat="server" >                             
                    </asp:HtmlEditorExtender>
                </div>
            </td>

        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

However the buttons are rendeing without the icons. How can I resolve this?

[image: HTMLExtender Example]

**Edit**

I was able to work around this issue by placing another `HtmlEditorExtender` and `TextBox` outside the repeater and hide it with jquery.

```
<div id="hideme">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEdit2" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="0px" Width="0px"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender1" DisplaySourceTab="false" TargetControlID="txtEdit2" EnableSanitization="false" runat="server">
    </asp:HtmlEditorExtender>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function pageLoad() {

            hideFalseEditor();
        }

        function hideFalseEditor(sender, args) {

            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#hideme').hide();

            });

        }

</script>
```

This seems a bit odd, but works. Perhaps a better solution?